# Having trouble locating an element with in an iframe using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am attempting to click a button using an XPath but I am unable to locate the element. Complete noob here.

Here is the button element I copied:

```
  <button _ngcontent-ygw-c218="" class="btn"><span _ngcontent-ygw-c218="" translate="">SHOW ALL</span></button>
```

Here is my programming:

```
 ShowAll =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-SelectComponents"]/div[1]/button[1]')
 ShowAll.click()
```

I have tried the following solution I found online to no avail (I've also replaced the 'btn' with 'SHOW ALL', no luck there):

```
 driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('btn'))
 ShowAll =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-SelectComponents"]/div[1]/button[1]')
 ShowAll.click()
 driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Much appreciated.

EDIT: Here is a picture for reference. What am I doing wrong or what I can do to work around this issue?

[image: HTML for reference]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add time to make sure the element is available before asking selenium to pick it.
Try this:

```
import time
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('btn'))
time.sleep(5) #you can change the 5 depending on the number that works
ShowAll =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-SelectComponents"]/div[1]/button[1]').click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I have tried this. I receive the following error: 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="btn"]"}

Answer (score 0):

The element with the text as ***SHOW ALL*** is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#iParts")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn > span[translate]"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='iParts']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn']/span[text()='SHOW ALL']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)